Python str subclass with lazy evaluation of its value (for argparse)
I am building a command-line program that uses argparse.
In the (assumed-to-be) rare case of a wrong call, argparse will show a description string supplied when creating the ArgumentParser.
I want this description to show the version number of my program.
I want to extract this from the pyproject.toml file via tomllib.
Since this is an expensive operation (and even more so since I want to learn how to do it), I would like the description string to be evaluated lazily: only when it is actually to be printed.
I have not yet found a way to do it even though I am willing to build a one-trick-pony object specialized for this particular value:

collections.UserString could provide the lazy evaluation (via overriding __getattribute__ for the data attribute), but, alas, some code in argparse uses re.sub() on it, which appears to check isinstance(x, str), which a UserString does not fulfill.
a subclass of str can override any operation done on a string -- but not perform lazy evaluation for a plain use of the entire string. (Is this true?)
if ArgumentParser would use str(description) instead of description when it is about to print the description, one could supply an object that performs the lazy evaluation in its __str__ method. But, alas, ArgumentParser does not do this.

Is there any approach that does the job?

In a roundabout way: don't set description, and only set it just before ArgumentParser would format the help.
import argparse
import time


class MyArgParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def format_help(self):
        if not self.description:
            print("Now thinking hard...")
            time.sleep(3)
            self.description = "An application!"
        return super().format_help()


ap = MyArgParser()
ap.add_argument("--foo", help="foo")
args = ap.parse_args()
print(args)

This program is fast when run without arguments, or with --foo=bar, and takes its sweet time when you run with --help.

Comment 1: A very good solution for my specific problem -- in just 7 minutes! Can ChatGPT beat this? I submitted the same wording and got a solution based on the same idea, but the code was awfully bloated: 2 classes, 5 functions instead of 1 class, 2 functions (it provided the toml-reading logic as well). I still love StackOverflow.

Comment 2: I'd still be interested to learn whether the lazy evaluation str problem can be solved in a general way in Python.

Comment 3: When I asked ChatGPT (in the same session) "Is there a general approach for the lazy evaluation of strings in Python?", it suggested (and correctly discussed the limitation of) the Object-with-a__str__-method approach, but then claimed that ArgumentParser(description=str(LazyDescription(get_version)) would solve my problem. This is utter nonsense -- but difficult to recognize as such if  somebody were only half-fluent in Python.

There's a reason I don't use ChatGPT for programming, and a reason why AI-generated answers are prohibited on Stack Overflow... :) Anyway, I don't think there is a generic lazy string that would work for any and all cases; for instance, I noticed argparse internally does if "%prog" in self.description or similar early on, so that'd cause evaluation anyway...
